# How to limit a text to a single line from java source file?

Tags: java, android

I can find how to limit a sentence to a single line that is defined in my java code. My text is passed through an intent. Here's what I'm experimenting with-

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message);

    Intent intent=getIntent();
    String message=intent.getStringExtra(MyActivity.EXTRA_VALUE);
    TextView text=new TextView(this);
    text.setTextSize(40);
    text.setText(message);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams p = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    p.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF,R.id.imageView);
    p.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_TOP);


    RelativeLayout layout=(RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.content);
    text.setLayoutParams(p);
    layout.addView(text);

    }
```

My corresponding xml file is-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:id="@+id/content"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="shanky.thefirst.DisplayMessageActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_display_message">

    <ImageView 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

My output is-

Welcome

Vivek!

instead of-
 Welcome Vivek!

Comment: Here the message is coming with new line character code , check with that.

Comment: Try removing newline chars using something like message.replaceAll("\n", "")

Comment: Maybe I couldn't convey my problem that well I have used no new line character codes. It's just that text is too big for mobile screen so switches to a new line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you want. Just do:

```
text.setSingleLine();
```

it will set your textview to single line